# Unable to Iterate through the function's properties and methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties, iteration

I was wondering if it was possible to iterate through methods and properties of the Object function (or similar built-in functions)

I can iterate through the document and window object via `for(var key in window) console.log(key)`

However, the 'Object' being a function does not work that way.  As I saw at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible) there are plenty of methods for it, for instance - `Object.isExtensible()` However, `for(var key in Object) console.log(key)` will only return `undefined`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

```
// functions directly within Object
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object).forEach(function(name) {
  // do whatever you want with the name here
}

// methods of Object instances
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype).forEach(function(name) {
  // do whatever you want with the name here
}
```